# Docker ps and other subcommands all hang forever on CentOS 7.2

Tags: docker, centos7

On a CentOS7.2 box, with Docker 1.10.3, I've successfully set up a simple docker image to run at boot using systemd. The container runs fine, and does what it's supposed to do (just runs apache to serve some content in a mapped volume).

What's odd is that if I log into the box where it's running, sudo to root, and then run "`docker anysubcommandbutversion`" ("`ps`", "`info`", et cetera), it just sits there and hangs forever, until I ^C it.

I see from https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/12606 , that this might be a FAQ, but I haven't seen a clear solution to this.

Comment: I don't know what was going on here, but I eventually stopped my service running the image, and at that point, I was able to run docker subcommands. However, I still can't remove any of the existing containers with commands like "docker rm <id from docker ps -a>". It would complete, but it wouldn't remove the container. I eventually just removed "/var/lib/docker/containers/*" and rebooted.